# Python script: problems with shebang line (unix)

Tags: python, bash, shebang

I am trying to get a feel for the Flask microframework by launching a test application to local server. When trying to run my code, `app.py`, I keep getting the error message:

```
-bash: ./app.py: /flask/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Here is the basic code [(taken from here)](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask) for `app.py`, which lives in my todo-api directory:

```
#!/flask/bin/python
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello, World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I've checked the file path to the python interpreter, and it should exist:

```
:bin $ pwd python

Users/me/Documents/Python/todo-api/flask/bin
```

I have followed the tutorial to the T; I've tried changing the shebang line to:

```
#!/flask/bin/python2.x
#!flask/bin/python
#!/flask/bin/env python
```

But to no avail. I am not that knowledgeable about bash, and have tried looking up what is going on, but the solutions to folks with similar problems have not worked for me; is there something going on behind the scenes that I am not understanding?

Comment: From the bash prompt, run `type python` and report the results.

Comment: @John1024 the result of `type python` yields the result: `python is hashed (/usr/bin/python)`

Comment: Then try `#!/usr/bin/python`.

Comment: @John1024 I've done this, and it also doesn't work; I think this is referring to the place where my system-wide python interpreter is installed. Following the tutorial, I used `virtualenv`

Comment: can you try `sed -n l app.py` ?  It is for displaying non-visible characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash shebangs expect an absolute path to the interpreter. So in your case you need to specify the full path to your Python interpreter i.e.:

```
#!/Users/me/Documents/Python/todo-api/flask/bin
```

You might want to investigate the use of `/usr/bin/env python` to be able to use the interpreter that is available in your user's `$PATH` environment variable. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12736/how-does-usr-bin-env-know-which-program-to-use/12751#12751

Comment: If you don't know the actual path of the interpreter you are using (in the case that your assumption is incorrect) try inspecting `sys.executable` in any code that you run.

Comment: Thanks, this has resolved the issue. I didn't realize that I needed the full path to call the interpreter I had set up in the virtual environment. I am now dealing with a separate issue with `Flask`, but I'll take some time to look into that. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

`pwd` tells you the current directory. It doesn't tell you where a command is located. The output from that command is a red herring.

You may be looking for `which python`. Put that path into your shebang line. Note that this will give you the Python interpreter from your `$PATH`, which may or may not be the right one.

The standard shebang line for Python scripts is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: Thanks for the info on `pwd`. Unfortunately, when I try `which python` it shows me where my system-wide python interpreter is installed. For the `flask` tutorial, I've used `virtualenv`

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue with trying to setup a python script as an executable for testing some things and realized that bash was getting in the way more than it was helping. I ended up setting up pyinstaller (which is incredibly easy) and then making my script a stand alone executable without bash being in the mix.

**Here's what I did (only takes a couple of minutes and no config):**
First; pyinstaller needs: build-essential & python-dev

*apt-get install build-essential python-dev*
(or yum, etc... depending on your OS)

Then use the built in python package manager to setup pyinstaller:
*pip install pyinstaller*

That's it. Run: pyinstaller --onefile myapp.py   (or pyinstaller.exe if your OS needs exe)

If it's successful (and it usually is), your new executable will be in a folder "Dist" in the same area you ran pysinstaller.